# How to classify shapefile values in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, shapefile, classification

I would like to classify shapefile values using graduated style in QGIS, but instead of using the default mode of classification (e.g.natural breaks with values range 0-10, 10-20, 20-30), I would like to set the values range to 0-10, 11-20, 21-30. Is it possible?

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please note that a good question on this site is expected to show some degree of research on your part, i.e. what you have tried and - if applicable - code so far. For more info, you can check our [faq].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Rule based classification, i.e. create a rule for each of the intervals. But be careful with the use of > greater than and >= greater than or equal.

To put this more into perspective, consider the following example:

First interval: `value > 0 AND value < 10`

Second interval: `value >= 10 AND value < 20`

If you don't use the `>=` for the second interval and just use `>`, and you happen to have a value of exactly 10, this value will be omitted from the classification.

Is your field integer or real?